# when i click in button, it's need to go for other activity according to the spinner?

Tags: android, button, spinner

Here is my code.
When I select agosto - 2013... calendar control stops

```
btok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (texto.equals("Julho - 2013")){
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                                julho.class);
                        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    } else if (texto.equals("Agosto - 2013")){
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                            agosto.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    } 
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a setOnItemClickListener rather than an onClickListener.